# How to create a response from a generic class containing HttpContext data in .Net 5 Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net5

I've started a new project using .Net 5 (my previous was .Net Framework 4.7). I'm writing a web API project and I want all my controllers/action responses to be of a certain type. This allows me to put some info I want included in every response, such as the current user info (and more stuff too).
My generic response looks like this (I've only left the relevant code):

```
public class MyResponse<T>
{
    public T data { get; set; }
    public User user { get; set; }
    public MyResponse(T inputData)    
    {
        data = inputData;
    }
}
```

And I set the response on a controller's action this way:

```
public IActionResult Get()
{
    var response = new MyResponse<string>("Hello");
    return Ok(response);
}
```

So the idea is that the response always contains a "data" property with the actual data, and a bunch of other properties with metadata.

The problem is how to include information on the logged in user in .Net 5. In .Net 4.x you could just access **HttpContext** from anywhere, so you could just populate the User property. But this is not possible in .Net 5

I'm going crazy trying to understand how to achieve this in .Net 5.

The first thing I've tried is DI (which I'm new to, so I might not be understanding this properly).

The first thing I tried is to make my User class depend on **IHttpContextAccessor** as most documentation points to:

```
public class User : IIdentity

{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    public User(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
}
```

and register it this way on startup.cs:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddTransient<User>();
```

But that doesn't work well, since when I try to create my User class within **MyResponse** class:

```
var user = new User(); // This doesn't work, as the constructor requires one argument
```

So the constructor requires one argument so I can't create the class like that. I (believe) I would need to create the User from the DI container, but I don't have access to that on **MyResponse** class (or at least I couldn't really understand how to do it or if possible at all).

I could pass the **HttpContext** from the controller to **MyResponse**, but that seems plain wrong (plus, there might be other people writing controllers, so I think it's better if they don't explicitly need to pass that to the response, should be handled transparently)

My concrete questions:

Any thoughts of how can I get hold of the HttpContext within my custom response class?
Should I be looking for an alternative option (such as a Middleware or Filter) to generate my response?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a factory along with dependency injection.

Create your user class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Security.Principal;

public class User : IIdentity
{
    private IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor { get; }
    public User(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.HttpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public string AuthenticationType => this.HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.AuthenticationType;

    public bool IsAuthenticated => this.HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

    public string Name => this.HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
}
```

Use DI to inject factories with the types you want:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddSingleton(a => GetResponse<string>(a));
services.AddSingleton(a => GetResponse<int>(a));
services.AddSingleton(a => GetResponse<decimal>(a));

Func<T, MyResponse<T>> GetResponse<T>(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var contextAccessor = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
    var user = new User(contextAccessor);

    return (data) => new MyResponse<T>(user, data);
}
```

Then inject it where you want:

```
namespace WebAppFiles.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class MyController : ControllerBase
    {
        private Func<int, MyResponse<int>> ResponseFactory { get; }

        public MyController(Func<int, MyResponse<int>> responseFactory)
        {
            this.ResponseFactory = responseFactory;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get([FromQuery] int value)
        {        
            return Ok(this.ResponseFactory(value));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response @SBFrancies, I appreciate it. This approach does work, I think the only downside is having to define all possible MyResponse<T> in advance, but it's not that big of a deal (unless we end up with a ton...).